# Chainsaw quiver variety and parabolic bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, hyperkaehler, quiver-varieties

How can we relate chainsaw quiver varieties with ADE type Nakajima quiver varieties?

We know that we can obtain ADE type quiver varieties (instantons over ALE spaces) by taking $\Gamma$ equivariant part of ADHM quiver (instantons over $\mathbb{C}^2$), here $\Gamma$ is some finite group inside $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$, and the corresponding categorical result is,

$\mathrm{Dcoh}_{\Gamma}(\mathbb{C}^2)\cong \mathrm{Dcoh}(\widetilde{\mathbb{C^2}/\Gamma})$.

For some pair of scheme and divisor $(X, D)$ (in our question let’s say $X=\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1, D={0}\times\mathbb{P}^1)$ the category of parabolic vector bundles is category equivalent to usual vector bundles over some orbifold. Since Chainsaw quiver varieties is isomorphic to moduli space of framed parabolic vector bundles over $(X, D)$. I wonder can we give a purely quiver-type argument to relate chainsaw quiver varieties and ADE type Nakajima quiver varieties?

I’m sorry for my poor knowledge about algebraic geometry so I can not state the second categorical equivalence explicitly.